# Не могу добавить изображение Django

Tags: html, django, изображения

Пытаюсь передать изображение в html код.

models.py

```
def firstSite(request):
images = loadImage.objects.all()
return render(request, "site.html", locals())
```

site.html

```
{% for image in images %}
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt="">
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

Но вместо "static/clientImgBase/eggs-1.png"

Присоединяет "polls/static/clientImgBase/eggs-1.png"
Так происходит, даже есть передать "Hello World!"
Получаю "polls/Hello World"

Comment: Что такое `loadImage`?

Comment: В моделях class loadImage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="static/clientImgBase")

Comment: Если так, то строчка `{{ image.url }}` вообще не должна работать. потому что image это экземпляр loadImage, а loadImage не содержит никакого url, вы что-то не договариваете

Comment: Да, уже пробовал другие варианты, и забыл вернуть. Сейчас исправил код. Не работает по прежнему.